# CSS: Set background image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to use stylesheet to set background image in my DIV on html page.

My css file:

```
#MyDiv {
background-image: url('Images/prechod.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 400px;
}
```

And my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="Css/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MyDiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried also this and it works.

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 400px; background-image: url('Images/prechod.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x">

    </div>
</body>
```

But I would like to have everything in the css file. I hope it's simple and somebody will help me.

Comment: Maybe you have problem with paths ('Images' vs. 'images')? Check with browser developer tools if this image is being found by browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths in your css file are relative to the location of the CSS file, not the HTML file.

You probably just need to change your CSS accordingly - for example if your css file is in `Css/StyleSheet1.css` relative to the HTML file, just change it to this:

```
#MyDiv {
    background-image: url('../Images/prechod.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 400px;
}
```

If it isn't a path issue, most likely you have some other style of higher specificity overriding the `#myDiv` declaration in your CSS file (for example something like `body #myDiv { background: none }` or similar).  That would explain why it works as an inline style (as these are of the highest specificity) but not in your stylesheet.  However based on the fact that your path was incorrect to begin with I would suspect that is the culprit.

Comment: OK... I'm stupid and I had to go home today :) Thanks

Comment: @JendaMatejicek no problem!  We all spend time debugging silly oversights like that! Mark one of these as the answer when you get a chance please :)

Answer (score 2):

```
background-image: url('../Images/prechod.png');
```

The Path has to be set relative to the css

Comment: OK... I'm stupid and I had to go home today :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths in the CSS and then adding those in there:

```
/**  CSS  **/
#MyDiv { url('../Images/prechod.png') repeat-x; height: 400px; }
```